# Django save before leaving page prompt

Tags: django

How can I prompt the user to hit the save button in a django template before they navigate away to a different page, and avoid losing the data they've entered?

I've seen various ways of doing this (such as [this django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1636/)) however I've not managed to get this working and was wondering if there's a way of doing it in django without having to use javascript or JQuery. Or do I just have to man up and work out how to use javascript within django?